# Statically resolved string conversion function in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to create a function in F# that will convert certain types to a string, but not others. The objective is so that a primitive can be passed but a complex object cannot be passed by accident. Here's what I have so far:

```
type Conversions =
    static member Convert (value:int) =
        value.ToString()
    static member Convert (value:bool) =
        value.ToString()

let inline convHelper< ^t, ^v when ^t : (static member Convert : ^v -> string) > (value:^v) =
    ( ^t : (static member Convert : ^v -> string) (value))

let inline conv (value:^v) = convHelper<Conversions, ^v>(value)
```

Unfortunately, my `conv` function gets the following compile-time error:

```
A unique overload for method 'Convert' could not be determined based on type information
prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed. Candidates: 
    static member Conversions.Convert : value:bool -> string, 
    static member Conversions.Convert : value:int -> string
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need a catch-all overload. This trick is typically used for extending built-in functions and operators, and the catch-all provides the default behavior. Which means you probably won't be able to use this to limit an argument to only a few types.

Comment: You're right, adding the catch-all overload works, but that kind of defeats the purpose. I wanted the compiler to catch when the wrong argument types were passed. If I have a catch-all overload I have to  throw an exception at runtime when the wrong argument types are passed. Other examples I have seen don't have one, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194565/null-coalescing-operator-in-f

Comment: What about using a measure type?

Comment: Don't think a measure type is applicable here - the point was just to clean up some code by not having to explicitly convert values to string but still maintain type-safety. I eventually wanted to add option conversion as well. The funny thing is this seems more elementary than other similar examples I have seen, yet it doesn't work. Basically I'm just trying to work-around the fact that I can't overload a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
type Conversions = Conversions with 
    static member ($) (Conversions, value: int) = value.ToString()
    static member ($) (Conversions, value: bool) = value.ToString()

let inline conv value = Conversions $ value

conv 1 |> ignore
conv true |> ignore
conv "foo" |> ignore //won't compile
```

Comment: That worked! I added my own answer to further expound on what I was trying to do. However, I am still curious why the original didn't work. It seems that there is something special about operators that allows them to have better type inference while still allowing overloads. Interesting!

Comment: @luksan Take a look at FsControl ( https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl ) and FSharpPlus ( https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus ) for things like this. In particular, conversions to string like the one you mention here: https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus/blob/master/FSharpPlus/Operators.fs#L156

Answer (score 4):

For some reason it seems using `(^t or ^v)` in the constraint instead of just `^v` makes it work.

```
type Conversions =
    static member Convert (value:int) =
        value.ToString()
    static member Convert (value:bool) =
        value.ToString()

let inline convHelper< ^t, ^v when (^t or ^v) : (static member Convert : ^v -> string)> value =
    ( (^t or ^v) : (static member Convert : ^v -> string) (value))

let inline conv value = convHelper<Conversions, _>(value)
```

Of course it means the function will also compile if the argument's type has a static method `Convert` from itself to string, but it's highly unlikely to ever bite you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Daniel's answer worked. Here's what I wanted in the end:

```
type Conversions = Conversions with
    static member ($) (c:Conversions, value:#IConvertible) =
        value.ToString()
    static member ($) (c:Conversions, value:#IConvertible option) =
        match value with
        | Some x -> x.ToString()
        | None -> ""

let inline conv value = Conversions $ value
```

The `IConvertible` interface type is just a convenient way for me to capture all primitives.

This results in the following behavior (FSI):

```
conv 1         // Produces "1"
conv (Some 1)  // Produces "1"
conv None      // Produces ""
conv obj()     // Compiler error
```